# Alterar nome das colunas "id" de um retorno sql

Tags: sql

Quero realizar uma consulta *SQL* e alterar o nome das colunas no resultado pois tenho 3 colunas `id`.

Atualmente o meu *SQL* esta assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shopweb_tipo as st 
INNER JOIN shopweb_categoria AS sc 
INNER JOIN shopweb AS s 
WHERE s.categoria = sc.id 
    AND s.tipo = st.id
```

Já tentei fazer assim porem não consegui resultado.

```
SELECT * 
FROM shopweb_tipo as st 
INNER JOIN shopweb_categoria AS sc 
INNER JOIN shopweb AS s 
WHERE s.categoria = sc.id 
    AND s.tipo = st.id 
    AND shopweb.id as "id_shopweb"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que descrever as colunas ao invés de colocar o `*` e dar um alias para elas exemplo:

```
SELECT
    st.id AS [apelido para o id],
    [demais_campos st],
    sc.id AS [apelido para o id],
    [demais_campos sc],
    s.id AS [apelido para o id],
    [demais_campos s]
FROM
    shopweb_tipo AS st
INNER JOIN shopweb_categoria AS sc
INNER JOIN shopweb AS s
WHERE
    s.categoria = sc.id
AND s.tipo = st.id
```

Claro, e chamar os demais campos na consulta também.

Outra maneira é buscar só o campo id e depois os demais campos, porém o campo ID vai vir duas vezes, uma com alias outro sem

```
SELECT
    st.id AS [apelido para o id],
    st.*,
    sc.id AS [apelido para o id],
    sc.*,
    s.id AS [apelido para o id],
    s.*
FROM
    shopweb_tipo AS st
INNER JOIN shopweb_categoria AS sc
INNER JOIN shopweb AS s
WHERE
    s.categoria = sc.id
AND s.tipo = st.id
```

Comment: Mas não seria muito viável, imagine cada tabela contendo 9 a 15 campos e soma-se uma media de 40 campos, seria uma query enorme.

Comment: você pode repetir o campo ID? porque dai poderia fazer de outra maneira, já edito a resposta

Comment: só os campos ID sim, por que preciso de cada id separado e quando puxo com php não sei qual estou pegando.

Comment: Então com o segundo exemplo, resolve seu problema

Comment: Sim resolveu, foi exatamente oque eu precisava, não tem problemas para me o id se repetir já que na aplicação eu especifico.

Comment: Beleza, se puder aceitar a resposta, agradeço ;)

Comment: Esperando o tempo para aceitar.